# Finding smallest positive root $\sqrt{\sin(1-x)}=\sqrt{\cos x}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Finding smallest positive root of the equation $\sqrt{\sin(1-x)}=\sqrt{\cos x}$

Try: $\sin(1-x)=\cos x= \sin\bigg(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\bigg)$

$1-x=n\pi+(-1)^n\bigg(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\bigg)$

Could some help me to solve it, Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $n$ is even, then the equation becomes

$$1-x=n\pi +\frac\pi2 -x$$

which simplifies to
$$1=n\pi + \frac\pi2$$

which is clearly not true for any value of $n\in\mathbb N$.

---

For odd values of $n$, the equation is

$$1-x=n\pi -\frac\pi2 + x$$

simplifying to

$$1-n\pi + \frac\pi2 = 2x$$

and is solvable for $x$.

---

This gives you a set of **candidate** values for $x$ which you then still need to check, because if $\sin(1-x)<0$, then $x$ cannot be a solution!

Comment: Neither can there be a solution if $\cos x\lt 0$

Answer (score 2):

If you square both sides, and apply sum of angles formula, you get

$$\sin 1\cos x - \sin x \cos 1 = \cos x.$$

Divide by $\cos x \cos 1$ to get

$$\tan 1 -\tan x = \sec 1$$

so that $x = \arctan(\tan 1 - \sec 1).$

This is not as satisfying as @5xum 's answer, but I thought it was interesting.

Comment: Just a small doubt.  Shouldn't that be $\sin 1\cos x \color{red}{-} \sin x \cos 1$

Comment: @Manthanein Yep.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem also it really is an interesting answer.(+1)